# How to remove red base glyph from my oh-my-posh/posh-git display?

Tags: git, powershell, fonts, posh-git, windows-terminal

I'm using windows terminal v1.0.1402.0 with powershell v7.0.1 with oh-my-posh and posh-git. I'm currently getting the following red base glyph when I open up my terminal.

[image: Red Glyph Error]

I've installed and tried using MesloLGL NF and Cascadia Mono PL for the fonts which both should work with oh-my-posh.

Here is my powershell profile:

```
Import-Module posh-git
Import-Module oh-my-posh
Set-Theme Paradox
```

Here is my windows terminal settings

```
 "defaults":
        {
            "colorScheme":  "One Half Dark",
            //"fontFace": "MesloLGL NF"
            "fontFace": "Cascadia Mono PL"
            // Put settings here that you want to apply to all profiles.
        },
        "list":
        [   
            {
                // Make changes here to the powershell.exe profile
                "guid": "{61c54bbd-c2c6-5271-96e7-009a87ff44bf}",
                "name": "Windows PowerShell",
                "commandline": "pwsh.exe",
                "useAcrylic": true,
                "acrylicOpacity": 0.8,
                "hidden": false
            },
```

I get this error regardless of what directory I'm in.

If it helps, here are my theme settings too: (Side note: The error count just went to 1, when I printed this before it was still 0)

```
PromptSymbols        : {SegmentBackwardSymbol, RootSymbol, PromptIndicator, VirtualEnvSymbol...}
CurrentHostname      : MyHost
MyThemesLocation     : C:\MyPath\PowerShell\PoshThemes
CurrentThemeLocation : C:\MyPath\PowerShell\Modules\oh-my-posh\2.0.412\Themes\Paradox.psm1
GitSymbols           : {BeforeIndexSymbol, LocalStagedStatusSymbol, DelimSymbol, BranchUntrackedSymbol...¦}
Options              : {ConsoleTitle, OriginSymbols}
ErrorCount           : 1
CurrentUser          : user
Colors               : {GitForegroundColor, GitDefaultColor, PromptForegroundColor, VirtualEnvBackgroundColor...¦}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by referencing this https://superuser.com/q/1424905/1183235 question. I listed all my powershell profiles, saw one that initialized conda and removed it. Now it works!

To list all powershell profiles:

```
$PROFILE | Format-List -Force
```

Comment: Notice that this is also a useful feature, i.e. when you activate your conda environment, it also shows the conda environment name where "base" is right now.

Answer (score 3):

To those who encounter this behaviour and do not want to fully remove the oh-my-posh integration with conda like the accepted answer says, there is one way of fixing the unknown glyph.

The extra glyphs used can be obtained by using a patched version of Cascadia Code from [Nerd Fonts](https://www.nerdfonts.com/font-downloads). Look for the one called Caskaydia Cove. After downloading, open each font file and install it. Then the font can be set in Windows Terminal options (press `Ctrl+,`) and replace the default font as below:

```
"fontFace" : "CaskaydiaCove Nerd Font",
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqjfV.png) is how the prompt should look now.

Answer (score 0):

Add

> $sl.PromptSymbols.VirtualEnvSymbol = ''

at the bottom of Paradox's theme file (or current theme's file)